# activeFocus very unreliable in TestCase

Tags: qml

How can I make QML TestCase behave more predictably when doing keyboard navigation tests, where I check various steps using `compare()` and the `activeFocus` of an element?

Right now, the tests are randomly passing and failing with no repeatability. So badly, in fact, that even **THIS** fails randomly:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtTest 1.1

TestWindow {
    TestCase {
        when: windowShown
        name: 'Example test'
        property string myView: 'mainView.homeWrapper.mainView.myView'

        // Some other tests, but should not matter for the below

        function test_5_keyboard () {
            var testView = getElement(myView)
            var uiUpButton = findChild(testView, 'catalogUpButton')

            uiUpButton.forceActiveFocus()
            wait(500)
            compare(uiUpButton.activeFocus, true)
        }
    }
}
```

Results randomly (but quite often, about 50 % of runs) in:

```
test-ui_1  | FAIL!  : qmltestrunner::Example test::test_5_keyboard() Compared values are not the same
test-ui_1  |    Actual   (): false
test-ui_1  |    Expected (): true
test-ui_1  |    Loc: [/app/test/tst_MyTest.qml(100)]
```

The same happens in "real" tests too, where I don't use `forceActiveFocus()` but simply check for `activeFocus` of an element after moving the keyboard using for example `keyClick(Qt.Key_Down)`. They often work, but again, fail randomly but too often to be usable.

The tests are run inside a container running Ubuntu 16.04, using these libraries:

```
RUN apt-get install -y qtcreator

# Install modules required by qml
RUN apt-get install -y \
    qml-module-qtquick-localstorage \
    qml-module-qt-websockets \
    libqt5qml-graphicaleffects \
    qt5-default \
    qtdeclarative5-test-plugin

# Install XVFB virtual display
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb
```

Comment: Try `when: windowShown` in your `TestCase` object.

Comment: @Mitch: hmm, it already has that too, was just left out of the example above. Added it now to the example.